# In LibreOffice Calc: how to position the cursor AFTER a selection when cutting/copying?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I sometimes have to cut a lot of cells from a spreadsheet, and copy them to another sheet.

I select the cells using the keyboard, hit CTRL-X, paste them to another sheet, and then return to the initial sheet to select more cells.

Thae annotance is that the selected cell/cursor remains at the beginning of the cell block I previously selected (which is now empty, because of the CTRL-X cut). I have to manually move the curser down again to the next block of cells I want to cut.

I could swear that I once got it to work how I wanted to: that the active cell/cursor moves as I select the cells. Hence, when I come back to the sheet, I'm ready to go to select the foloowing cells. But I can't find that option or any related keywords anywhere.

Comment: After selecting the range/cells, press Shift+Enter to move to the last select cell. Or after cutting the range/selction, you can press Ctrl+Down Arrow, to select the first cell after the last selected.

Comment: Thanks! I think CTRL+Down will help me, because it seems to jump to the next not empty space of the now empty block. A bit strange, but ah well.

I can't seem to mark your comment as an answer, though?

Comment: You couldn't mark it because it was just a comment. I have now answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Select the range/cells.
2. After selecting the range/cells, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to move to the last select cell. Or after cutting the range/selection, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> Arrow, to select the first cell after the last selected.